# How to change the labels of chartjs doughnut chart with multiple data sets

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Can any one help me how to display the legend label colors according to the graph [image: Colors according to the graph]

i am attaching a codesandbox also similar to my working env https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-night-p7e4z?file=/src/demo/DoughnutChartDemo.js

Comment: If you try pressing the `A` legend label you can see that it hides all the first values, since there are multiple values chart.js takes the color from the first one for its legend, thats why `B` is grey because all those colors are grey, seems like when there is no data available it takes the first color again

Comment: @LeeLenalee yes you are correct but is there any way to modify this to get the output as shown in fig please help me